# Resizing and moving an image

Tags: php, image

I'm kind of a beginner in PHP and here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Recieve an uploaded image and move it to temp/ folder
2. Examine it and decide whether it needs to be resized or not (it needs, if it's not 135px wide)
3. If needs to be resized, resize it and save as results/{number}_cover.jpg
4. If it doesn't, copy an uploaded image right away to the same place, without resizing

And here's my code:

```
            $target_path = "temp/";
            $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES["file" . $a]["name"]); 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file" . $a]["tmp_name"], $target_path);

            list($current_width, $current_height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($target_path);
            if($current_width != 135) {
                $filename = $a . "_cover.jpg";
                $result_image = "results/" . $filename;
                $writing = fopen($result_image, 'w');
                $scale = (135 / $current_width);
                $new_width = 135;
                $new_height = $current_height * $scale;
                $result_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                $current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_path);
                imagecopyresampled($result_image, $current_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $current_width, $current_height);
                imagejpeg($result_image, null, 100);
                fclose($writing);
            } else {
                $target_path = "results/";
                $target_path = $target_path . $a . "_cover.jpg"; 
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file" . $a]["tmp_name"], $target_path);
            }
```

However, this is what this code does for me:
 1. If an image needs resizing, it just give me an image data to the browser instead of saving it to the file
 2. If it doesn't need resizing, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: do you have results folder in the right place and does it give you any error?

Comment: https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage an excellent tool for showing and/or saving images!

Comment: `imagejpeg` needs a file name as second parameter. Giving `null` will result in `imagejpeg` sending it out to the browser. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php